# Read/Write/Edit SharePoint 2013 Data inside Visual Basic Windows Application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-studio-2013, datasource

Does anybody have any experience with creating a windows application with a SharePoint 2013 data source?  I have a couple of apps that read/download library files and read/write lists.  This all works very well. But, when it comes to creating a new record, I'm having a bit of a struggle trying to add a person to the "Assigned To" field in a Task list.  Also, I'm not finding a way to update an existing custom list.  I'm trying to check a checkbox field.  I've used the Data Source Wizard to connect to the SharePoint 2013 sites.  So I can accomplish what I need, except for these 2 things.  So any guidance will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 provides client SDK to perform CRUD, you could use the client SDK for your requirement.

```
Namespace Microsoft.SDK.SharePointServices.Samples
Class DeleteListItem

    Shared Sub Main ()

        Dim siteUrl As String = "http://MyServer/sites/MySiteCollection"

        Dim clientContext As New ClientContext(siteUrl)
        Dim oList As List = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements")
        Dim oListItem As ListItem = oList.GetItemById(2)

        oListItem.DeleteObject()

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
    End Sub
End Class
```

End Namespace

One sample thread.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649783/sharepoint-csom-how-to-update-person-or-group-field-using-validateupdatelistite

More details below.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee539976(v=office.14).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2